# Scanning a package with mypy yields different result on different machines

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I'm trying to type-check [the latest revision of my code](https://github.com/exhuma/puresnmp/tree/4fb26c4e5b6817944d75d11b0b332440a386190a) and get inconsistent results using the ALE plugin in vim and `mypy` on the command line.

> **Update**: After the comments from @aaron below, I checked out the code on a different machine, and it works as expected: I get more errors there, than on my main development machine. So ALE inside vim gives me the same results as the process on another machine. And I don't understand why.

Both *should* give me the same, but I noticed that ALE gives me more results than the command line. And I wonder what I am doing wrong with the CLI invocation of `mypy`.

To set up and environment to reproduce the behaviour I am experiencing (ALE is not required):

- Clone the repository linked above and checkout revision `4fb26c4e5b`
- Run `python3 -m venv env`
- Run `./env/bin/pip install -e .`
- Run `./env/bin/pip install mypy`

Now, using this environment, type-checking the directory `puresnmp` yields the following:

```
$ ./env/bin/mypy puresnmp
puresnmp/aio/api/raw.py:505: error: Type signature has too few arguments
puresnmp/api/pythonic.py:239: error: Type signature has too few arguments
puresnmp/api/raw.py:490: error: Type signature has too few arguments
puresnmp/test/asyncmock.py:18: error: 'yield' in async function
Found 4 errors in 4 files (checked 38 source files)
```

Using either `./env/bin/mypy puresnmp/**/*.py` or `./env/bin/mypy -p puresnmp` yields the same report as above.

However, when specifying a file explicitly, I get way more errors (which happen to correspond to the ALE errors):

```
$ ./env/bin/mypy puresnmp/api/pythonic.py
puresnmp/x690/types.pyi:58: error: Return type "Union[Null, UnknownType]" of "from_bytes" incompatible with return type "Type[bytes]" in supertype "Type"
puresnmp/transport.py:83: error: Argument 1 to "Timeout" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"
puresnmp/pdu.py:178: error: Argument 2 to "Sequence" has incompatible type "Union[str, bytes, int, datetime, timedelta, None]"; expected "Type[Any]"
puresnmp/pdu.py:217: error: On Python 3 '%s' % b'abc' produces "b'abc'"; use %r if this is a desired behavior
puresnmp/pdu.py:253: error: Argument 2 to "VarBind" has incompatible type "Null"; expected "Union[str, bytes, int, datetime, timedelta, None]"
puresnmp/pdu.py:316: error: Argument 2 to "VarBind" has incompatible type "Null"; expected "Union[str, bytes, int, datetime, timedelta, None]"
puresnmp/pdu.py:320: error: Argument 2 to "Sequence" has incompatible type "Union[str, bytes, int, datetime, timedelta, None]"; expected "Type[Any]"
puresnmp/pdu.py:365: error: On Python 3 '%s' % b'abc' produces "b'abc'"; use %r if this is a desired behavior
puresnmp/api/raw.py:104: error: Incompatible return value type (got "List[Union[ObjectIdentifier, Union[str, bytes, int, datetime, timedelta, None]]]", expected "List[Type[Union[str, bytes, int, datetime, timedelta, None]]]")
puresnmp/api/raw.py:160: error: Argument 1 to "VarBind" has incompatible type "Union[ObjectIdentifier, Union[str, bytes, int, datetime, timedelta, None]]"; expected "Union[ObjectIdentifier, str]"
puresnmp/api/raw.py:160: error: Argument 2 to "VarBind" has incompatible type "Union[ObjectIdentifier, Union[str, bytes, int, datetime, timedelta, None]]"; expected "Union[str, bytes, int, datetime, timedelta, None]"
puresnmp/api/raw.py:164: error: Unsupported left operand type for < ("ObjectIdentifier")
puresnmp/api/raw.py:317: error: Argument 2 to "VarBind" has incompatible type "Type[Union[str, bytes, int, datetime, timedelta, None]]"; expected "Union[str, bytes, int, datetime, timedelta, None]"
puresnmp/api/raw.py:336: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Dict[str, Union[ObjectIdentifier, Union[str, bytes, int, datetime, timedelta, None]]]", expected "Dict[str, Type[Union[str, bytes, int, datetime, timedelta, None]]]")
puresnmp/api/raw.py:460: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Union[ObjectIdentifier, Union[str, bytes, int, datetime, timedelta, None]]", target has type "Type[Union[str, bytes, int, datetime, timedelta, None]]")
puresnmp/api/raw.py:490: error: Type signature has too few arguments
puresnmp/api/raw.py:566: error: Argument 1 to "len" has incompatible type "ObjectIdentifier"; expected "Sized"
puresnmp/api/raw.py:570: error: Argument 1 to "tablify" has incompatible type "List[VarBind]"; expected "Iterable[Tuple[Any, Any]]"
puresnmp/api/raw.py:587: error: Argument 1 to "len" has incompatible type "ObjectIdentifier"; expected "Sized"
puresnmp/api/pythonic.py:104: error: Item "str" of "Union[ObjectIdentifier, str, bytes, int, datetime, timedelta, None, Any]" has no attribute "pythonize"
puresnmp/api/pythonic.py:104: error: Item "bytes" of "Union[ObjectIdentifier, str, bytes, int, datetime, timedelta, None, Any]" has no attribute "pythonize"
puresnmp/api/pythonic.py:104: error: Item "int" of "Union[ObjectIdentifier, str, bytes, int, datetime, timedelta, None, Any]" has no attribute "pythonize"
puresnmp/api/pythonic.py:104: error: Item "datetime" of "Union[ObjectIdentifier, str, bytes, int, datetime, timedelta, None, Any]" has no attribute "pythonize"
puresnmp/api/pythonic.py:104: error: Item "timedelta" of "Union[ObjectIdentifier, str, bytes, int, datetime, timedelta, None, Any]" has no attribute "pythonize"
puresnmp/api/pythonic.py:104: error: Item "None" of "Union[ObjectIdentifier, str, bytes, int, datetime, timedelta, None, Any]" has no attribute "pythonize"
puresnmp/api/pythonic.py:154: error: Argument 1 to "VarBind" has incompatible type "Union[ObjectIdentifier, Union[str, bytes, int, datetime, timedelta, None]]"; expected "Union[ObjectIdentifier, str]"
puresnmp/api/pythonic.py:154: error: Item "str" of "Union[ObjectIdentifier, Union[str, bytes, int, datetime, timedelta, None]]" has no attribute "pythonize"
puresnmp/api/pythonic.py:154: error: Item "bytes" of "Union[ObjectIdentifier, Union[str, bytes, int, datetime, timedelta, None]]" has no attribute "pythonize"
puresnmp/api/pythonic.py:154: error: Item "int" of "Union[ObjectIdentifier, Union[str, bytes, int, datetime, timedelta, None]]" has no attribute "pythonize"
puresnmp/api/pythonic.py:154: error: Item "datetime" of "Union[ObjectIdentifier, Union[str, bytes, int, datetime, timedelta, None]]" has no attribute "pythonize"
puresnmp/api/pythonic.py:154: error: Item "timedelta" of "Union[ObjectIdentifier, Union[str, bytes, int, datetime, timedelta, None]]" has no attribute "pythonize"
puresnmp/api/pythonic.py:154: error: Item "object" of "Union[ObjectIdentifier, Union[str, bytes, int, datetime, timedelta, None]]" has no attribute "pythonize"
puresnmp/api/pythonic.py:169: error: Argument 1 to "VarBind" has incompatible type "Union[ObjectIdentifier, Union[str, bytes, int, datetime, timedelta, None]]"; expected "Union[ObjectIdentifier, str]"
puresnmp/api/pythonic.py:169: error: Item "str" of "Union[ObjectIdentifier, Union[str, bytes, int, datetime, timedelta, None]]" has no attribute "pythonize"
puresnmp/api/pythonic.py:169: error: Item "bytes" of "Union[ObjectIdentifier, Union[str, bytes, int, datetime, timedelta, None]]" has no attribute "pythonize"
puresnmp/api/pythonic.py:169: error: Item "int" of "Union[ObjectIdentifier, Union[str, bytes, int, datetime, timedelta, None]]" has no attribute "pythonize"
puresnmp/api/pythonic.py:169: error: Item "datetime" of "Union[ObjectIdentifier, Union[str, bytes, int, datetime, timedelta, None]]" has no attribute "pythonize"
puresnmp/api/pythonic.py:169: error: Item "timedelta" of "Union[ObjectIdentifier, Union[str, bytes, int, datetime, timedelta, None]]" has no attribute "pythonize"
puresnmp/api/pythonic.py:169: error: Item "object" of "Union[ObjectIdentifier, Union[str, bytes, int, datetime, timedelta, None]]" has no attribute "pythonize"
puresnmp/api/pythonic.py:185: error: Argument 1 to "VarBind" has incompatible type "Union[ObjectIdentifier, Union[str, bytes, int, datetime, timedelta, None]]"; expected "Union[ObjectIdentifier, str]"
puresnmp/api/pythonic.py:239: error: Type signature has too few arguments
puresnmp/api/pythonic.py:258: error: The return type of a generator function should be "Generator" or one of its supertypes
puresnmp/api/pythonic.py:272: error: Argument 1 to "len" has incompatible type "ObjectIdentifier"; expected "Sized"
puresnmp/api/pythonic.py:282: error: The return type of a generator function should be "Generator" or one of its supertypes
puresnmp/api/pythonic.py:296: error: Argument 1 to "len" has incompatible type "ObjectIdentifier"; expected "Sized"
Found 45 errors in 5 files (checked 1 source file)
```

How can this difference be explained?

And more importantly: How can I get all the errors without specifying each file manually?

Comment: What is `./env/bin/pip install -e .[dev, test]` supposed to do? On commit `4fb26c4e5b`, both `./env/bin/mypy puresnmp` and `./env/bin/mypy -p puresnmp` yield `Found 80 errors in 8 files (checked 38 source files)`.

Comment: The `pip install...` command will install the package in "editable" mode including all dependencies from the extras `dev` and `test`. For me it's not reporting any errors though. I will try on another machine. Maybe something is wrong with my global setup...

Comment: What extras? I get `Invalid requirement: 'test]'`.

Comment: This will pull in the extras from [setup.py](https://github.com/exhuma/puresnmp/blob/4fb26c4e5b6817944d75d11b0b332440a386190a/setup.py#L55). The error-message suggests that you somehow enter the command incorrectly. Maybe a shell-issue? Try to enclose it in quotes? Or escape the brackets? What shell do you use?

Comment: ... actually, thinking about it, you don't really need any extras to reproduce the issue I have. I will edit the question and remove them.

Comment: I use bash. Quotes worked. Still getting `Found 80 errors in 8 files (checked 38 source files)` though.

Comment: Interesting... on another machine it works fine and I also get all the errors. So I suspect there's either a system-wide or user-wide setting getting in the way. I will need to investigate this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was having several Python versions installed via `penv`.

At the time I created the virtual environment for ALE/vim, I hat my Python version set to a different one then at the moment when I ran `mypy` manually.

This led to different results because the typing was updated in between those versions.

Cleaning everything up and ensuring that the Python versions were the same solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that by default when you pass a folder, for `mypy` it means `scan this package`. So it follows imports. (this case `./env/bin/mypy puresnmp`)

When you pass python files list as args - it scans the files list.

Check more details on the docs website https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-follow-imports

https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#following-imports

### To run `mypy` on all files

I think you should be able to run the utility on all the python files in a folder you can run it like `./env/bin/mypy $(find puresnmp -name "*.py")`

Comment: After seeing the comment from @aaron, I tested it with the exact same incantation on another machine and it works as expected. Using the package name is fine and *should* work without specifying the files. There is some other system-setting which gets in the way. I will update the question with that detail.

Comment: Additionally, if you look at the question, it says that it checked 38 source files which is correct. So it actually *does* follow the imports correctly as far as I can tell.